# how to change direction of toolTip extjs 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip, tabpanel

I want to change the direction of my tab's tooltip.

I want to make it align to the top.

My code is like this  :

```
var toolTip = 'test';

var panelExpertCharts = Ext.create('ContainerListChartExpert', {                        
                        chartList: chartList,
                        layout: standardLayout,
                        idIndicator: idIndicator,
                        idOrganisation: organisationObj.id,
                        title: chartList[0].titleExpert,
                        closable: true,                     
                        tabConfig: {                            
                             tooltip: toolTip
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks for reply.

Hamza.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change a tooltip alignment in the following way

```
 listeners: {
        render: function(c) {
              new Ext.ToolTip({
                 target: 'trackCallout',
                 anchor: 'right',
                 html: 'Test Tooltip'
              });
            }
        }
```

You can check a very good example  [here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/qtips/qtips/viewer.html)  from sencha .

Comment: I can not give an ID to my object unfortunately, and the target property must take an id .. !!